# Indefinite stall OR Error 66 on flutter pub publish

Tags: flutter, dart

## Environment

- `flutter pub version` Pub 2.14.3
- OS version:  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Windows 10 Pro 20H2

## Problem

I am building a package with the 'plugin' template and am unable to push to it pub.dev. As of now, if I run `flutter pub publish --dry-run -v` or  `flutter pub pub publish --dry-run -v` on Ubuntu, even after running `flutter pub cache repair` and `flutter pub pub cache repair`, I get the following log:

```
[  +11 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[ +165 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' `is` not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +145 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[  +74 ms] Using /home/zues/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache for the pub cache.
[        ] executing: /home/zues/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/pub publish --dry-run -v
FINE: Pub 2.14.3
FINE: Archiving and publishing Instance of 'Package'.
MSG : Publishing lexactivator 3.0.0 to https://pub.dartlang.org:
***insert directory tree here
FINE: Creating .tar.gz stream containing:
***insert project files here
IO  : Spawning "git --version" in /home/zues/lexactivator/.
IO  : Finished git. Exit code 0.
    | stdout:
    | | git version 2.17.1
    | Nothing output on stderr.
FINE: Determined git command git.
IO  : Spawning "git check-ignore --quiet ." in /home/zues/lexactivator/.
IO  : Finished git. Exit code 1.
    | Nothing output on stdout.
    | Nothing output on stderr.
IO  : Spawning "git ls-files --cached --exclude-standard --recurse-submodules" in /home/zues/lexactivator/.
IO  : Finished git. Exit code 0.
    | stdout:
    | | .gitignore
    | | CHANGELOG.md
    ***insert project files here
    | Nothing output on stderr.
```

The command then stalls. I have left the system as is for an hour with no yield.
This is my project root pubspec (not the example pubspec):

```yaml
name: lexactivator
description: LexActivator API wrapper for Dart. Integrates Crypltex's services into the Dart language.
version: 3.0.0
homepage: https://cryptlex.com

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=2.5.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  ffigen: ^4.0.0  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  
  
flutter:
  plugin:
    platforms:
      linux:
        pluginClass: LexactivatorPlugin
      macos:
        pluginClass: LexactivatorPlugin
      windows:
        pluginClass: LexactivatorPlugin
```

Furthermore, on Windows, the same commands as above yield:

```
ERR : Directory listing failed, path = '.\example\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\lexactivator\example\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\lexactivator\example\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\lexactivator\windows\include\lexactivator\*' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
    | , errno = 3)
FINE: Exception type: FileSystemException
FINE: dart:io
 _Directory.listSync
    | package:pub/src/validator/gitignore.dart 43:50
 GitignoreValidator.validate.<fn>
    | package:pub/src/ignore.dart 293:28
 Ignore.listFiles
    | package:pub/src/validator/gitignore.dart 41:43
 GitignoreValidator.validate
    | package:pub/src/validator.dart 156:64
 Validator.runAll.<fn>
    | dart:async
 Future.wait
    | package:pub/src/validator.dart 156:19
 Validator.runAll
    | package:pub/src/command/lish.dart 245:21
 LishCommand._validate
    | package:pub/src/command/lish.dart 219:15
 LishCommand.runProtected
    | dart:async
 new Future.sync
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 112:12
 captureErrors.wrappedCallback
    | package:stack_trace
 Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 125:11
 captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command.dart 171:13
 PubCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 209:27
 CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 168:24
 PubCommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 153:20
 PubCommandRunner.run
    | package:dartdev/dartdev.dart 45:56
 runDartdev
    | C:\b\s\w\ir\cache\builder\sdk\pkg\dartdev\bin\dartdev.dart 11:9 
 main
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async
 Future.catchError
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 112:52
 captureErrors.wrappedCallback
    | package:stack_trace
 Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 125:11
 captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command.dart 171:13
 PubCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 209:27
 CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 168:24
 PubCommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 153:20
 PubCommandRunner.run
    | package:dartdev/dartdev.dart 45:56
 runDartdev
    | C:\b\s\w\ir\cache\builder\sdk\pkg\dartdev\bin\dartdev.dart 11:9 
 main
[+8233 ms] "flutter publish" took 8,334ms.
[   +4 ms] pub finished with exit code 66
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit
           (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      _DefaultPub.interactively
           (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:391:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      PackagesForwardCommand.runCommand
           (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/packages.dart:247:5)   
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>

(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)       
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)       
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      CommandRunner.runCommand
           (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)  
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)       
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand

(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)  
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>        
           (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)       
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)  
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +236 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 229ms
[   +6 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +1 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 66
```

### Expected behaviour

As there is scarce documentation about the fine-details of the pub publish command (which might not be required), as per what I have found on the internet, I expect the command to at least stop with errors yet it just stalls on Ubuntu, and on Windows it throws an error I haven't found much data about.

I was on the latest dev channel release at first which I thought was the cause of the problem but I switched to stable and even rebuilt the project to try again but had no luck so far.

This post is a duplicate of my Github Issue [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/3172). Help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was closed here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/3172

Turns out it was because the `pub publish` program was following a symlink in `/<project-root>/example/linux/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks`. Similarly for Windows. Removing the folder should solve the issue.